# Can't get the default spinner to work - why?

Tags: android, android-spinner

The default `Spinner` is not working its showing blank.I have `setAdapter` before `setSelection` but still it is not working.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

CategorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
CategorySpinner.setSelection(0);
```

spinnerArray is initialised in this method:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) { 
if (data.moveToFirst()) { 
do { 
    int categoryNameColumnIndex = 
    data.getColumnIndex(CategoryBaseColumns.CATEGORY_NAME); 
    spinnerArray.add(data.getString(categoryNameColumnIndex)); 
    //Log.e(data.getString(categoryNameColumnIndex)) 
    } while (data.moveToNext()); 
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Check _spinnerArray_ should not be empty.

Comment: what is isnide spinnerARRAY?

Comment: public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
            if (data.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int categoryNameColumnIndex = data.getColumnIndex(CategoryBaseColumns.CATEGORY_NAME);
                    spinnerArray.add(data.getString(categoryNameColumnIndex));
                    //Log.e(data.getString(categoryNameColumnIndex))

                } while (data.moveToNext());
            }


        }

Answer (score 0):

More context would be beneficial but from what I can see I assume that your `spinnerArray` is populated in an asynchronous way. That means that the `spinnerArray` you're passing to the `ArrayAdapter` is empty and items are added to it only after `onLoadFinished` is called but the `ArrayAdapter` is never notified by this.

What I would suggest is to take the `ArrayAdapter` initialisation and move it into a separate method and call it in the `onLoadFinished` method.

Example:

```
public void setSpinnerData(ArrayList<String> spinnerArray) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    CategorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    CategorySpinner.setSelection(0);
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) { 
    ArrayList<String> spinnerArray = ArrayList();
    if (data.moveToFirst()) { 
        do { 
            int categoryNameColumnIndex = data.getColumnIndex(CategoryBaseColumns.CATEGORY_NAME); 
            spinnerArray.add(data.getString(categoryNameColumnIndex)); 
            //Log.e(data.getString(categoryNameColumnIndex)) 
        } while (data.moveToNext()); 
    }
    setSpinnerData(spinnerArray);
}
```